# How to get the values from the formatted string?

Tags: android, timer, format, string-formatting, countdowntimer

I have an app which counts down the time.

I formatted a string like this:

```
String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", hour, min, sec);
```

It will be for example 01:42:12.

I would like to know how to do this in the reverse order?
I would like to get 3 values divided by ':'.

How to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you may use `DateFormat` for that purpose:

```
DateFormat tf = DateFormat.getTimeInstance()
String str = tf(new Date());    // gives you current time '01:05:06'
Date d = tf.parse(str);         // parses it back to the Date
```

otherwise there's a `SimpleDateFormat` and many other ways to skin a cat.